# How do I sort items in a 2-line horizontal flatlist?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to sort the clocks in the application as in the picture. But I can't do this correctly.

[image]

I wrote as below. But I could not do the operation correctly as in the picture below. What do I need to do to sort these clocks exactly as above?

[image]

```js
import React from "react"
import { FlatList, ScrollView, Text, View } from "react-native"

const ScreenA = () => {

    const time = ["01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"]

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, width: 100 }}>
                <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (

        <ScrollView
            horizontal={true}
        >
            <FlatList
                data={time}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                numColumns={Math.ceil(time.length / 2)}
            />
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

export default ScreenA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this can be done with a flat list, especially since horizontal number of columns isn't supported. But seeing that you have scroll disabled anyway I figured you might not actually need the flat list approach. Flat list is used for scrolling lists usually large lists because it virtualizes the list for performance.

Here is a solution that will work for the example you posted above using the flex styling built into React Native.

```
  const itemsArray = [
    '01:00',
    '02:00',
    '03:00',
    '04:00',
    '05:00',
    '06:00',
    '07:00',
    '08:00',
    '09:00',
    '10:00',
    '11:00',
    '12:00',
  ];
  const numOfRows = 2;
  const numOfColumns = itemsArray.length / numOfRows;

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      {Array.from({ length: numOfColumns }).map((item, columnIndex) => (
        <View key={`Row_${columnIndex}`} style={{ flex: 1 / numOfColumns }}>
          {itemsArray.slice(numOfRows * columnIndex, columnIndex * numOfRows + numOfRows).map((item, index) => (
            <View key={`Item_${index}`} style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', aspectRatio: 1, margin: 1 }}>
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
```

This solution could be cleaned up a little and put in a grid component with passed props for 'items', 'number of columns' and 'number of rows'.

Hope this solution works for you!

Comment: I'm sorry it's not working. The hours are increasing to the right the way you did

Comment: Oh, Wow I misunderstood you want it to look like the top picture? I thought you wanted the bottom picture. Sorry that makes a lot of sense now. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way i forgot to remove scrollEnabled={false} line. Actually it doesn't work even though it is attached. So I need to be able to scroll on the horizontal axis.

Comment: I updated my solution to work for your use case. You should be able to just wrap this solution in a scrollview to get scrolling.